# How do I prevent text from flowing onto different sections of a page?

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm building a web page using horizontal parallax. I've taken a long page and divided it up into different `div` tags. However, how do I keep text to a specific section and not have it flowing onto a different portion of the page? I've tried `word-wrap: break-word` but to no avail. Website: http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/

HTML:

```
<div id="transition-slide-container">               
            <div id="transition-slide"><!--begin transition-slide-->           
                <div class="slide" id="home"><!--begin home-->
                    <div id="inner-container">
                        <div id="title"><h2>Hey there!</h2></div>   
                        <div class="row" id="homepage">
                                       <div class="small-12 columns">
                                            <p>Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. </p>
                                       </div>
                                  </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end home-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#transition-slide-container {    
    background: #bee1ff;    
    padding-top: 128px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    width: 400%;        
}
div#inner-container {
     margin-left: 0;
}
div#transition-slide {
     white-space: nowrap;
     left: 0;
}
.slide {
     display: inline-block;
     min-width: 24.99%;
     margin: 0 auto;    
     z-index: 1;
 }
 div#inner-container {
     text-align: left;
     max-width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0;
 }
 div#inner-container p {    
     font-size: 24px;
     word-wrap: break-word; 
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `white-space: normal;` on your `.inner-container` to make text wrap inside it

Answer (score 0):

I agree with koala_dev , however I'd like to add why this is happening even if your words are spaced, the reason is because you are setting text to not wrap here:

```
div#transition-slide {
 white-space: nowrap;
 left: 0;
}
```

So removing this `white-space: nowrap;` from this selector you can make sure that the text wraps and this way you don't need to add extra markup to make it wrap.

To reiterate you are saying: Don't wrap... then Wrap... why not just not say don't wrap and let it wrap by default?

On a side note if you are worried about the text not wrapping when you are adding words that don' have spaces (long URL's for example) then the text tends to flow outside it's container... then you can use `word-wrap: break-word;` in your CSS parent container.

Comment: He needs to disable wrapping on the main container so all the "slides" line up horizontally

Answer (score -1):

ok what you want to do is make a max-width or just a width on every div there, because i notice that there are no max-widths and widths on everything there so make sure you have a width on everything because a div can overlap another div if it dosent have any width set. Also